# git automatically keep template synced

Tags: git, synchronization, fork, pull

I have a repository, let's call it `template`. This `template`-repository gets forked by multiple other repositories, let's call them `leafs`. Note, however, that I may use multiple `template`-repositories for one `leaf`-repository. One might say, they have an m to n relationship.

My question is, how can I keep those `leaf`-repositories automatically up-to-date with the `template`-repositories? Let's say `template`-repository-1 has a bug and I fixed it inside the repository. I now wouldn't want to update every `leaf`-repository manually, but instead this should go as automatically as possible.

Ideally, a new branch with the name "sync/reposiotry_name" would be automatically created together with a merge request, but I am open to other ideas.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not write a script?

Comment: I have thought about that and it is certainly a possible solution. I actually found some code I could expand on: 
https://github.com/imkarrer/fork-sync/blob/master/updateForkedBranch.sh 
But I would prefer a built-in method or existing best practices, if there are any.

Comment: Git doesn't have built-in automatic syncing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712591/git-automatic-sync-branch-in-real-time